# specify which button triggered a form submission into an ASP.NET app

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms

Into an ASP.NET MVC aplication, I use a form with several submit buttons.
I can route them to the correct controller action this way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post))
...
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="action1"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="action2"  />
```

Then my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Validate_Form(..., String submit_button)
        {
switch submit_button {
    ...
   }
}
```

This works perfectly.

Now I d like to include a JS action before submitting the form.
So I change the input submit to an input button and add an onclick event this way:

```
  <input type="button" name="submit_button" value="action1" class="col-md-2" onclick="JSaction()" />
```

JS function:

```
function JSaction(){
...my stuff
document.getElementById('formName').submit();
}
```

And then, when the controller Validate_Form method is run, it looses its submit_button argument (null value).
Can you explain me why?
How can I solve this issue?

thx in advance.

Comment: Why don't you send the argument during the onclick to your script JSaction('mybuttonname') and do something from there like put the value in a hidden field?

Comment: Yes this could surely work if noone comes up with a cleaner idea.